# How to change the name of figure caption?

Tags: captions, babel

I know that this have been asked many times. I've tried different solutions, however none of them is working for me. I would like to change the identifier of the caption for pictures from "Fig. " to "Abb. ". I am using babel. So far I have tried:
1.:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb. }
```

2.:

```
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb. }
```

3.:

```
\captionsetup{figurename=Abb. }
```

None of this has changed anything. I am using this code as a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\addto\captionsgerman{
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Images/Simulink/PT1_Glied_s.png}
    \caption{PT1-Glied}
    \label{fig:fig_pt1glied}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the `article` class your change of `\figurename` works. I assume then that your problem is something to do with the `paper` class.. Many years ago I could read German, but no longer,  so it would take me far too long to figure out your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `paper` class you need to redefine `\figureshortname`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\addto\captionsgerman{\renewcommand{\figureshortname}{Abb.}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Images/Simulink/PT1_Glied_s.png}
    \caption{PT1-Glied}
    \label{fig:fig_pt1glied}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the `paper` class not specify this? If it does then a user should read it. --- GOM

Comment: @PeterWilson the class manual does not mention it, I guess the author didn't consider the situation that people want to change the names.

Comment: Thank you very much! The \figureshortname was the part missing, as you have mentionend.